# How to sum a value grouped by product and year in SAS?

Tags: sum, sas

I need to get the sum value of volume for each stock in each year.
The data looks like

```
Date    ID    volume
2009    BA     100
2009    BA     20
2011    BA     100
2009    VOD    100
2009    VOD    150
2009    VOD    100    
2013    BT     300
...    ...     ...
```

What I want is

```
Date    ID    sumvolume
2009    BA     120
2011    BA     100
2009    VOD    350   
2013    BT     300
...    ...     ...
```

I used code

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *, (select sum(volume) from data as sub where sub.data=main.date)as sumvolume
from data as main;
quit;
```

but this one only gave the sumvolume in each year instead of sumvolume for each stock in each year.

Anyone can help me with code ? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a group by statement to use summary functions (like sum()) across the groups defined by variables in the group by statement.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as select
    date,
    id,
    sum(volume) as sumvolume
    from data
    group by id, date;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the total sum of stock per year since you are using `where sub.date=main.date`. If you would add `and sub.ID = main.ID` to the `where` clause, you would get it per product. But that is not your expected behavior, this since you keep every individual observation by having `*` in your `select` statement and no `group by` statement.

Instead of a subquery on the `data` table, you could use `group by` to accomplish your wanted behaviour.

```
input Date ID $ volume;
datalines;
2009    BA     100
2009    BA     20
2011    BA     100
2009    VOD    100
2009    VOD    150
2009    VOD    100
2013    BT     300
;

data work.want;
input Date ID $ sumvolume;
datalines;
2009    BA     120
2011    BA     100
2009    VOD    350   
2013    BT     300
;


proc sql;
create table work.wanted as
select Date, ID, sum(volume) as sumvolume
from work.data
group by Date, ID
;
```

I'm leaving one thing to you, the sorting of the resulting table.

Answer (score 0):

If your source data isn't already sorted then do that first:

```
proc sort data=input ;
  by ID date;
run ;
```

Then you can do it in one simple pass:

```
data output(drop=volume) ;
  retain sumvolume ;
  set input ;
  by ID date ;
  if first.date then sumvolume=volume ;
  else sumvolume=sum(sumvolume,volume) ;
  if last.date then output ;
run ;
```